# AES шифрование с использованием Windows Forms (E0415 error)

Tags: c++, winforms, строки, visual-c++, консоль

Здравствуйте уважаемые программисты! У меня возникла следующая проблема:

Это MyForm.cpp

```
    #include "MyForm.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;


static const uint32_t rcon[10] = {
            0x01000000UL, 0x02000000UL, 0x04000000UL, 0x08000000UL, 0x10000000UL,
            0x20000000UL, 0x40000000UL, 0x80000000UL, 0x1B000000UL, 0x36000000UL
};

class AdvancedEncryptionStandard {
public:
    typedef struct {
        uint32_t eK[44], dK[44];    // encKey, decKey
        int Nr; // 10 rounds
    }AesKey;

#define BLOCKSIZE 16  // Длина пакета AES-128 составляет 16 байт

    // uint8_t y[4] -> uint32_t x
#define LOAD32H(x, y) \
  do { (x) = ((uint32_t)((y)[0] & 0xff)<<24) | ((uint32_t)((y)[1] & 0xff)<<16) | \
             ((uint32_t)((y)[2] & 0xff)<<8)  | ((uint32_t)((y)[3] & 0xff));} while(0)

// uint32_t x -> uint8_t y[4]
#define STORE32H(x, y) \
  do { (y)[0] = (uint8_t)(((x)>>24) & 0xff); (y)[1] = (uint8_t)(((x)>>16) & 0xff);   \
       (y)[2] = (uint8_t)(((x)>>8) & 0xff); (y)[3] = (uint8_t)((x) & 0xff); } while(0)

// Извлекаем n-й байт из младшего бита из uint32_t x
#define BYTE(x, n) (((x) >> (8 * (n))) & 0xff)

/* used for keyExpansion */
// замена байта, а затем поворот на 1 бит влево
#define MIX(x) (((S[BYTE(x, 2)] << 24) & 0xff000000) ^ ((S[BYTE(x, 1)] << 16) & 0xff0000) ^ \
                ((S[BYTE(x, 0)] << 8) & 0xff00) ^ (S[BYTE(x, 3)] & 0xff))

// uint32_t x поворачивается влево на n бит
#define ROF32(x, n)  (((x) << (n)) | ((x) >> (32-(n))))
// uint32_t x вращается вправо на n бит
#define ROR32(x, n)  (((x) >> (n)) | ((x) << (32-(n))))

/* for 128-bit blocks, Rijndael never uses more than 10 rcon values */
// постоянная раунда AES-128
    
    // S-поле
    unsigned char S[256] = {
            0x63, 0x7C, 0x77, 0x7B, 0xF2, 0x6B, 0x6F, 0xC5, 0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2B, 0xFE, 0xD7, 0xAB, 0x76,
            0xCA, 0x82, 0xC9, 0x7D, 0xFA, 0x59, 0x47, 0xF0, 0xAD, 0xD4, 0xA2, 0xAF, 0x9C, 0xA4, 0x72, 0xC0,
            0xB7, 0xFD, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3F, 0xF7, 0xCC, 0x34, 0xA5, 0xE5, 0xF1, 0x71, 0xD8, 0x31, 0x15,
            0x04, 0xC7, 0x23, 0xC3, 0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9A, 0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xE2, 0xEB, 0x27, 0xB2, 0x75,
            0x09, 0x83, 0x2C, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x6E, 0x5A, 0xA0, 0x52, 0x3B, 0xD6, 0xB3, 0x29, 0xE3, 0x2F, 0x84,
            0x53, 0xD1, 0x00, 0xED, 0x20, 0xFC, 0xB1, 0x5B, 0x6A, 0xCB, 0xBE, 0x39, 0x4A, 0x4C, 0x58, 0xCF,
            0xD0, 0xEF, 0xAA, 0xFB, 0x43, 0x4D, 0x33, 0x85, 0x45, 0xF9, 0x02, 0x7F, 0x50, 0x3C, 0x9F, 0xA8,
            0x51, 0xA3, 0x40, 0x8F, 0x92, 0x9D, 0x38, 0xF5, 0xBC, 0xB6, 0xDA, 0x21, 0x10, 0xFF, 0xF3, 0xD2,
            0xCD, 0x0C, 0x13, 0xEC, 0x5F, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17, 0xC4, 0xA7, 0x7E, 0x3D, 0x64, 0x5D, 0x19, 0x73,
            0x60, 0x81, 0x4F, 0xDC, 0x22, 0x2A, 0x90, 0x88, 0x46, 0xEE, 0xB8, 0x14, 0xDE, 0x5E, 0x0B, 0xDB,
            0xE0, 0x32, 0x3A, 0x0A, 0x49, 0x06, 0x24, 0x5C, 0xC2, 0xD3, 0xAC, 0x62, 0x91, 0x95, 0xE4, 0x79,
            0xE7, 0xC8, 0x37, 0x6D, 0x8D, 0xD5, 0x4E, 0xA9, 0x6C, 0x56, 0xF4, 0xEA, 0x65, 0x7A, 0xAE, 0x08,
            0xBA, 0x78, 0x25, 0x2E, 0x1C, 0xA6, 0xB4, 0xC6, 0xE8, 0xDD, 0x74, 0x1F, 0x4B, 0xBD, 0x8B, 0x8A,
            0x70, 0x3E, 0xB5, 0x66, 0x48, 0x03, 0xF6, 0x0E, 0x61, 0x35, 0x57, 0xB9, 0x86, 0xC1, 0x1D, 0x9E,
            0xE1, 0xF8, 0x98, 0x11, 0x69, 0xD9, 0x8E, 0x94, 0x9B, 0x1E, 0x87, 0xE9, 0xCE, 0x55, 0x28, 0xDF,
            0x8C, 0xA1, 0x89, 0x0D, 0xBF, 0xE6, 0x42, 0x68, 0x41, 0x99, 0x2D, 0x0F, 0xB0, 0x54, 0xBB, 0x16
    };

    // Обратный блок S
    unsigned char inv_S[256] = {
            0x52, 0x09, 0x6A, 0xD5, 0x30, 0x36, 0xA5, 0x38, 0xBF, 0x40, 0xA3, 0x9E, 0x81, 0xF3, 0xD7, 0xFB,
            0x7C, 0xE3, 0x39, 0x82, 0x9B, 0x2F, 0xFF, 0x87, 0x34, 0x8E, 0x43, 0x44, 0xC4, 0xDE, 0xE9, 0xCB,
            0x54, 0x7B, 0x94, 0x32, 0xA6, 0xC2, 0x23, 0x3D, 0xEE, 0x4C, 0x95, 0x0B, 0x42, 0xFA, 0xC3, 0x4E,
            0x08, 0x2E, 0xA1, 0x66, 0x28, 0xD9, 0x24, 0xB2, 0x76, 0x5B, 0xA2, 0x49, 0x6D, 0x8B, 0xD1, 0x25,
            0x72, 0xF8, 0xF6, 0x64, 0x86, 0x68, 0x98, 0x16, 0xD4, 0xA4, 0x5C, 0xCC, 0x5D, 0x65, 0xB6, 0x92,
            0x6C, 0x70, 0x48, 0x50, 0xFD, 0xED, 0xB9, 0xDA, 0x5E, 0x15, 0x46, 0x57, 0xA7, 0x8D, 0x9D, 0x84,
            0x90, 0xD8, 0xAB, 0x00, 0x8C, 0xBC, 0xD3, 0x0A, 0xF7, 0xE4, 0x58, 0x05, 0xB8, 0xB3, 0x45, 0x06,
            0xD0, 0x2C, 0x1E, 0x8F, 0xCA, 0x3F, 0x0F, 0x02, 0xC1, 0xAF, 0xBD, 0x03, 0x01, 0x13, 0x8A, 0x6B,
            0x3A, 0x91, 0x11, 0x41, 0x4F, 0x67, 0xDC, 0xEA, 0x97, 0xF2, 0xCF, 0xCE, 0xF0, 0xB4, 0xE6, 0x73,
            0x96, 0xAC, 0x74, 0x22, 0xE7, 0xAD, 0x35, 0x85, 0xE2, 0xF9, 0x37, 0xE8, 0x1C, 0x75, 0xDF, 0x6E,
            0x47, 0xF1, 0x1A, 0x71, 0x1D, 0x29, 0xC5, 0x89, 0x6F, 0xB7, 0x62, 0x0E, 0xAA, 0x18, 0xBE, 0x1B,
            0xFC, 0x56, 0x3E, 0x4B, 0xC6, 0xD2, 0x79, 0x20, 0x9A, 0xDB, 0xC0, 0xFE, 0x78, 0xCD, 0x5A, 0xF4,
            0x1F, 0xDD, 0xA8, 0x33, 0x88, 0x07, 0xC7, 0x31, 0xB1, 0x12, 0x10, 0x59, 0x27, 0x80, 0xEC, 0x5F,
            0x60, 0x51, 0x7F, 0xA9, 0x19, 0xB5, 0x4A, 0x0D, 0x2D, 0xE5, 0x7A, 0x9F, 0x93, 0xC9, 0x9C, 0xEF,
            0xA0, 0xE0, 0x3B, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x2A, 0xF5, 0xB0, 0xC8, 0xEB, 0xBB, 0x3C, 0x83, 0x53, 0x99, 0x61,
            0x17, 0x2B, 0x04, 0x7E, 0xBA, 0x77, 0xD6, 0x26, 0xE1, 0x69, 0x14, 0x63, 0x55, 0x21, 0x0C, 0x7D
    };

    /* copy in[16] to state[4][4] */
    int loadStateArray(uint8_t(*state)[4], const uint8_t* in) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                state[j][i] = *in++;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    /* copy state[4][4] to out[16] */
    int storeStateArray(uint8_t(*state)[4], uint8_t* out) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                *out++ = state[j][i];
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
    // Расширение ключа
    int keyExpansion(const uint8_t* key, uint32_t keyLen, AesKey* aesKey) {

        if (NULL == key || NULL == aesKey) {
            printf("keyExpansion param is NULL\n");
            return -1;
        }

        if (keyLen != 16) {
            printf("keyExpansion keyLen = %d, Not support.\n", keyLen);
            return -1;
        }

        uint32_t* w = aesKey->eK;  // Ключ шифрования
        uint32_t* v = aesKey->dK;  // Ключ дешифрования

        /* keyLen is 16 Bytes, generate uint32_t W[44]. */

        /* W[0-3] */
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            LOAD32H(w[i], key + 4 * i);
        }

        /* W[4-43] */
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            w[4] = w[0] ^ MIX(w[3]) ^ rcon[i];
            w[5] = w[1] ^ w[4];
            w[6] = w[2] ^ w[5];
            w[7] = w[3] ^ w[6];
            w += 4;
        }

        w = aesKey->eK + 44 - 4;
        // Матрица ключей дешифрования - это порядок, обратный матрице ключей шифрования, что удобно для использования. 11 матриц ek расположены в обратном порядке и присваиваются dk в качестве ключа дешифрования.
        // Т.е. dk [0-3] = ek [41-44], dk [4-7] = ek [37-40] ... dk [41-44] = ek [0-3]
        for (int j = 0; j < 11; ++j) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
                v[i] = w[i];
            }
            w -= 4;
            v += 4;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    // круглый ключ плюс
    int addRoundKey(uint8_t(*state)[4], const uint32_t* key) {
        uint8_t k[4][4];

        /* i: row, j: col */
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                k[i][j] = (uint8_t)BYTE(key[j], 3 - i); // Преобразование ключа uint32[4] в матрицу uint8 k[4][4] * /
                state[i][j] ^= k[i][j];
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    // Замена байта
    int subBytes(uint8_t(*state)[4]) {
        /* i: row, j: col */
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                state[i][j] = S[state[i][j]]; // Используем необработанные байты напрямую как индекс данных S-блока
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    // Обратная замена байта
    int invSubBytes(uint8_t(*state)[4]) {
        /* i: row, j: col */
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                state[i][j] = inv_S[state[i][j]];
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // Сдвиг строки
    int shiftRows(uint8_t(*state)[4]) {
        uint32_t block[4] = { 0 };

        /* i: row */
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            // Удобно для циклического сдвига строки, сначала поместите строку из 4 байтов в структуру uint_32, а затем преобразуйте ее в независимые 4 байта uint8_t
            LOAD32H(block[i], state[i]);
            block[i] = ROF32(block[i], 8 * i);
            STORE32H(block[i], state[i]);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    // Обратный сдвиг
    int invShiftRows(uint8_t(*state)[4]) {
        uint32_t block[4] = { 0 };

        /* i: row */
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            LOAD32H(block[i], state[i]);
            block[i] = ROR32(block[i], 8 * i);
            STORE32H(block[i], state[i]);
        }

        return 0;
    }

    /* Galois Field (256) Multiplication of two Bytes */
    // Двухбайтовая операция умножения поля Галуа
    uint8_t GMul(uint8_t u, uint8_t v) {
        uint8_t p = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
            if (u & 0x01) {    //
                p ^= v;
            }

            int flag = (v & 0x80);
            v <<= 1;
            if (flag) {
                v ^= 0x1B; /* x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1 */
            }

            u >>= 1;
        }

        return p;
    }

    // смесь столбцов
    int mixColumns(uint8_t(*state)[4]) {
        uint8_t tmp[4][4];
        uint8_t M[4][4] = { {0x02, 0x03, 0x01, 0x01},
                           {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01},
                           {0x01, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03},
                           {0x03, 0x01, 0x01, 0x02} };

        /* copy state[4][4] to tmp[4][4] */
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                tmp[i][j] = state[i][j];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {  // Сложение и умножение поля Галуа
                state[i][j] = GMul(M[i][0], tmp[0][j]) ^ GMul(M[i][1], tmp[1][j])
                    ^ GMul(M[i][2], tmp[2][j]) ^ GMul(M[i][3], tmp[3][j]);
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    // обратное микширование
    int invMixColumns(uint8_t(*state)[4]) {
        uint8_t tmp[4][4];
        uint8_t M[4][4] = { {0x0E, 0x0B, 0x0D, 0x09},
                           {0x09, 0x0E, 0x0B, 0x0D},
                           {0x0D, 0x09, 0x0E, 0x0B},
                           {0x0B, 0x0D, 0x09, 0x0E} };  // Используем обратную матрицу смешанной матрицы столбцов

        /* copy state[4][4] to tmp[4][4] */
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                tmp[i][j] = state[i][j];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                state[i][j] = GMul(M[i][0], tmp[0][j]) ^ GMul(M[i][1], tmp[1][j])
                    ^ GMul(M[i][2], tmp[2][j]) ^ GMul(M[i][3], tmp[3][j]);
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    // Интерфейс шифрования AES-128, длина входного ключа должна составлять 16 байтов, а длина входного сигнала должна быть целым числом, кратным 16 байтам.
    // Чтобы длина вывода была такой же, как длина ввода, вызов функции выделяет память для выходных данных извне
    int aesEncrypt(const uint8_t* key, uint32_t keyLen, const uint8_t* pt, uint8_t* ct, uint32_t len) {

        AesKey aesKey;
        uint8_t* pos = ct;
        const uint32_t* rk = aesKey.eK;  // Указатель ключа дешифрования
        uint8_t out[BLOCKSIZE] = { 0 };
        uint8_t actualKey[16] = { 0 };
        uint8_t state[4][4] = { 0 };

        if (NULL == key || NULL == pt || NULL == ct) {
            printf("param err.\n");
            return -1;
        }

        if (keyLen > 16) {
            printf("keyLen must be 16.\n");
            return -1;
        }

        if (len % BLOCKSIZE) {
            printf("inLen is invalid.\n");
            return -1;
        }

        memcpy(actualKey, key, keyLen);
        keyExpansion(actualKey, 16, &aesKey);  // Расширение секретного ключа

        // Используйте режим ECB для циклического шифрования данных с различной длиной пакета
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += BLOCKSIZE) {
            // Преобразование 16-байтового открытого текста в матрицу состояний 4x4 для обработки
            loadStateArray(state, pt);
            // круглый ключ плюс
            addRoundKey(state, rk);

            for (int j = 1; j < 10; ++j) {
                rk += 4;
                subBytes(state);   // замена байта
                shiftRows(state);  // сдвиг строки
                mixColumns(state); // смесь столбцов
                addRoundKey(state, rk); // круглый ключ плюс
            }

            subBytes(state);    // замена байта
            shiftRows(state);  // сдвиг строки
            // смешивание столбцов здесь не выполняется
            addRoundKey(state, rk + 4); // круглый ключ плюс

            // Преобразование матрицы состояний 4x4 в вывод одномерного массива uint8_t и сохранение
            storeStateArray(state, pos);

            pos += BLOCKSIZE;  // Указатель памяти зашифрованных данных переходит к следующему пакету
            pt += BLOCKSIZE;   // Указатель данных в виде открытого текста перемещается в следующую группу
            rk = aesKey.eK;    // Восстанавливаем указатель rk в начальную позицию секретного ключа
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // Расшифровка AES128, параметры такие же, как у шифрования
    int aesDecrypt(const uint8_t* key, uint32_t keyLen, const uint8_t* ct, uint8_t* pt, uint32_t len) {
        AesKey aesKey;
        uint8_t* pos = pt;
        const uint32_t* rk = aesKey.dK;  // Указатель ключа дешифрования
        uint8_t out[BLOCKSIZE] = { 0 };
        uint8_t actualKey[16] = { 0 };
        uint8_t state[4][4] = { 0 };

        if (NULL == key || NULL == ct || NULL == pt) {
            printf("param err.\n");
            return -1;
        }

        if (keyLen > 16) {
            printf("Длина ключа должна быть 16\n");
            return -1;
        }

        if (len % BLOCKSIZE) {
            printf("inLen .\n");
            return -1;
        }

        memcpy(actualKey, key, keyLen);
        keyExpansion(actualKey, 16, &aesKey);  // Расширение секретного ключа, как при шифровании

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += BLOCKSIZE) {
            // Преобразование 16-байтового зашифрованного текста в матрицу состояний 4x4 для обработки
            loadStateArray(state, ct);
            // Округление добавления секретного ключа, как при шифровании
            addRoundKey(state, rk);

            for (int j = 1; j < 10; ++j) {
                rk += 4;
                invShiftRows(state);    // обратный сдвиг
                invSubBytes(state);     // обратная замена байтов, порядок этих двух шагов может быть изменен на обратный
                addRoundKey(state, rk); // Округлить добавление секретного ключа, как при шифровании
                invMixColumns(state);   // обратное микширование
            }

            invSubBytes(state);   // обратная замена байта
            invShiftRows(state);  // обратный сдвиг
            // Обратного перемешивания здесь нет
            addRoundKey(state, rk + 4);  // Округление добавления секретного ключа, как при шифровании

            storeStateArray(state, pos);  // Сохраняем данные в виде открытого текста
            pos += BLOCKSIZE;  // Выводить указатель памяти данных на длину пакета сдвига
            ct += BLOCKSIZE;   // Указатель памяти входных данных сдвигает длину пакета
            rk = aesKey.dK;    // Восстанавливаем указатель rk в начальную позицию секретного ключа
        }
        return 0;
    }

    void printHex(uint8_t* ptr, int len, char* tag) {
        printf("%s\ndata[%d]: ", tag, len);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            printf("%.2X ", *ptr++);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    char StartAES(Char^ st) {
        
        const uint8_t key[16] = {
            0x2b, 0x7e, 0x15, 0x16, 0x28, 0xae, 0xd2, 0xa6, 0xab, 0xf7, 0x15, 0x88, 0x09, 0xcf, 0x4f, 0x3c
        };
        uint8_t pt[16] = {
            0x32, 0x43, 0xf6, 0xa8, 0x88, 0x5a, 0x30, 0x8d, 0x31, 0x31, 0x98, 0xa2, 0xe0, 0x37, 0x07, 0x34
        };
        uint8_t ct[16] = { 0 };     // Память вывода данных внешнего приложения, используемая для зашифрованных данных
        uint8_t plain[16] = { 0 };  // Внешнее приложение выводит память данных для расшифрованных данных

        aesEncrypt(key, 16, pt, ct, 16); // шифрование
        printHex(pt, 16, "plain data:"); // Распечатываем исходные данные в виде открытого текста
        printf("expect cipher:\n39 25 84 1D 02 DC 09 FB DC 11 85 97 19 6A 0B 32\n");  // Содержимое данных после обычной расшифровки

        printHex(ct, 16, "after encryption:");  // Распечатываем зашифрованный зашифрованный текст

        aesDecrypt(key, 16, ct, plain, 16);       // расшифровать
        printHex(plain, 16, "after decryption:"); // Выводим расшифрованные данные в виде открытого текста

        // case 2
        // 16-байтовая строка с секретным ключом
        const uint8_t key2[] = "1234567890123456";
        // Текстовая строка длиной 32 байта

        const uint8_t* data = (uint8_t*)"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456";
        uint8_t ct2[32] = { 0 };    // Внешнее приложение для памяти выходных данных, используемое для хранения зашифрованных данных
        uint8_t plain2[32] = { 0 }; // Внешнее приложение для памяти выходных данных, используемое для хранения расшифрованных данных
        // Шифровать 32-байтовый открытый текст
        aesEncrypt(key2, 16, data, ct2, 32);

        printf("\nplain text:\n%s\n", data);
        printf("expect ciphertext:\nfcad715bd73b5cb0488f840f3bad7889\n");
        printHex(ct2, 32, "after encryption:");

        // Расшифровка 32-байтового зашифрованного текста
        aesDecrypt(key2, 16, ct2, plain2, 32);
        // Распечатать расшифрованный открытый текст в шестнадцатеричной форме
        printHex(plain2, 32, "after decryption:");

        // Поскольку данные до шифрования представляют собой строку видимых символов, распечатайте расшифрованные символы открытого текста для сравнения с открытым текстом перед шифрованием
        printf("output plain text\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
            printf("%c ", plain2[i]);
        }

        return NULL;
    }
    std::string AESTEST(System::Char^ str) {
        return StartAES(str);
    }
}; AdvancedEncryptionStandard AES;

[STAThreadAttribute]
void main(array<String^>^ args) {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles;
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    
    Form1::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(% form);
}
```

это MyForm.h

```
    #pragma once
#include <Windows.h>

namespace Form1 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Сводка для MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: добавьте код конструктора
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ label_result;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ TextLable;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label2;

    protected:


    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Обязательная переменная конструктора.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Требуемый метод для поддержки конструктора — не изменяйте 
        /// содержимое этого метода с помощью редактора кода.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label_result = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->TextLable = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Tai Le", 14.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(0)));
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(344, 28);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(168, 23);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->label1->Text = L"AES ENCRYPTION";
            // 
            // label_result
            // 
            this->label_result->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::White;
            this->label_result->BackgroundImageLayout = System::Windows::Forms::ImageLayout::Center;
            this->label_result->Cursor = System::Windows::Forms::Cursors::Hand;
            this->label_result->ForeColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ControlText;
            this->label_result->Location = System::Drawing::Point(348, 292);
            this->label_result->Name = L"label_result";
            this->label_result->Size = System::Drawing::Size(152, 54);
            this->label_result->TabIndex = 1;
            this->label_result->Text = L"Зашифровать";
            this->label_result->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this->label_result->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button1_Click);
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(64, 120);
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(200, 20);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // TextLable
            // 
            this->TextLable->AutoSize = true;
            this->TextLable->Location = System::Drawing::Point(61, 90);
            this->TextLable->Name = L"TextLable";
            this->TextLable->Size = System::Drawing::Size(40, 13);
            this->TextLable->TabIndex = 3;
            this->TextLable->Text = L"Текст:";
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(562, 119);
            this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
            this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(200, 20);
            this->textBox2->TabIndex = 4;
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this->label2->AutoSize = true;
            this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(559, 90);
            this->label2->Name = L"label2";
            this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(126, 13);
            this->label2->TabIndex = 5;
            this->label2->Text = L"Зашифрованный текст:";
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::DarkTurquoise;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(856, 568);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->TextLable);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label_result);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"Advanced Encryption Standard";
            this->Activated += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button1_Click);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        System::String^ text1 = this->textBox1->Text;

        //System::String^ textAES = System::String::Empty;
        // AES Преобразование переменной text1 в зашифрованный вид в переменную textAES
        System::String^ textAES = AES.StartAES();

        this->textBox2->AppendText(textAES); // Добавляем в объект textBox2 текст переменной textAES
    }
    };
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку:
Серьезность    Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка (активно)    E0415   не существует подходящего конструктора для преобразования из "char" в "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator>"   Form1   D:\FloyzenCode\Projects\Visual Studio 2022\Form1\MyForm.cpp 468

Я хочу при нажатии кнопки button1_Click вызывалось шифрование AES и передавалось в textBox2. Буду всем очень благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string AESTEST(System::Char^ str) {
    return StartAES(str);
}
```

Итак, возвращается `string`. Вы пишете

```
return StartAES(str);
```

но эта функция

```
char StartAES(Char^ st) {
```

возвращает `char`. А такого преобразования — `char` в `string` — попросту нет... И компилятор, как мне кажется, пояснил об этом вполне однозначно.

Если вы хотите вернуть строку, состоящую из единственного символа — то можно сделать, например, так:

```
return string(1,StartAES(str));
```

Но вам виднее, что именно вы хотите и что делать. Простите, но разбираться в ваших исходниках, и верно ли она будет работать — это все же за рамками вопроса на ruSO...

Comment: Прошу прощения, я не понял, как мне реализовать, чтобы текст который вводит пользователь шифровался? То есть пользователь вводит текст, нажимает кнопку и в textBox2 выводился зашифрованный текст? Впервые использую winforms))

Comment: Сейчас функция с кнопкой выглядит вот так:
```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
  System::String^ text1 = this->textBox1->Text;

  System::String^ textAES = System::String::Empty;
  // AES Преобразование переменной text1 в зашифрованный вид в переменную textAES
  System::String^ textAES = AES.AESTEST(text1);

  this->textBox2->AppendText(textAES); // Добавляем в объект textBox2 текст переменной textAES
 }
```

Comment: Понимаете, вряд ли у кого-то будет время копаться в длинном коде и переделывать его... Конкретный вопрос — конкретный ответ, это да... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask